xsession unable to write to /tmp
Место в корневом каталоге /dev/sda1 заполнено на 100%
Попытался очистить место и перезапустить виртуалку, теперь при запуске выдает такую ошибку: xsession unable to write to /tmp
В режиме восстановления также выдает эту ошибку, как можно вручную очистить место вне виртуалки? Зайти в нее не могу и расширить место также

Залогиниться в другой tty без иксов есть возможность?

Спасибо, как раз заход в консоль помог

Перешел в консоль виртуалки (CTRL + F2)
Удалил vs code (из-за него закончилось место)
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/code

vscode был установлен не через пакетный менеджер?

Вообще можно было попробовать обойтись удалением /var/cache/apt
